# Sweetalert and jQuery.validationEngine

Tags: jquery, submit, form-submit, jquery-validation-engine, sweetalert

I have implemented Sweetalert on my jQuery.validationEngine but the button "Accept" of sweetalert doesn't run the "submit", What could add to make it work?

This is the code with Sweetalert:

```
                    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#id_form").validationEngine('attach',{
            onValidationComplete:function(form, status){
            if (status === true){
            if(swal({title: "Confirm text?",text: "Another Text",type: "warning",showCancelButton: true,confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",confirmButtonText: "Accept",cancelButtonText: "Cancel"closeOnConfirm: true,closeOnCancel: false})){       

        form.validationEngine('detach');
           submit();
                }}}
            });
           })
```

Without Sweetalert and running:

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#id_form").validationEngine('attach',{
            onValidationComplete:function(form, status){
            if (status === true){
                if(confirm("Confirm text?")){               

        form.validationEngine('detach');
           submit();
                }}}
            });
        })
```

References:

[Sweetalert](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/)

[jQuery.validationEngine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine)

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should insert comma after "Cancel" string.
Adapt your code according to below

```
swal({
                                title: "Confirm text?",
                                text: "Another Text",
                                type: "warning",
                                showCancelButton: true,
                                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                                confirmButtonText: "Accept",
                                cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
                                closeOnConfirm: true,closeOnCancel: false
                            }, function (isConfirm) {
                                if (isConfirm) {
                                    return true;
                                } else {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
```